# Android Give alert when music File will be added to sdcard

Tags: android, events, file

I like to give alert/notification when music File will be added to sdcard.How can I do that?
Can I get any event from os when a file is added to the system?

Comment: In this case above I used FileObserver, when a new file created event received,populated a notification.

Answer (score 3):

Use [a FileObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html) for this.

Example:

```
final MyFileObserver fo = new MyFileObserver("/mnt/sdcard/", FileObserver.CREATE);
Runnable run = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                fo.startWatching();
            }
        };
Thread t = new Thread(run);
t.run();
```